# Can we use more than 1 row in LOAD CSV(neo4j)?

Tags: csv, graph, neo4j, cypher, load-csv

LOAD CSV reads row by row and one can do any kind of operation on that row. Is it possible to use more than one row at a time, for example, say I want to assign a relationship where every i'th row is a friend of (i-1)'th row? Or is it possible to store values of previous rows in some local variables while the LOAD CSV is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think referring (i-1) row is possible with LOAD CSV.

Instead, you can add one column say friendID at the end of each row in CSV that has ID of (i-1) and then you need to do 2 scans over the same CSV.

Scan-1) This will create the Person nodes (friendID column will not be used)

Scan-2) This will create the relationships between Person nodes using the friendID column